# Customize Windows 11 window borders to look like Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-11, aero

I want to make window borders aesthetically look like Windows 7. It currently looks like this:

[image: Windows 11 borders]

I want it to look like this:

[image: Windows 7 borders]

This is also acceptable (DWM disabled):

[image: Disabled DWM borders]

I followed this tutorial: https://winaero.com/get-windows-7-theme-for-windows-10.
I installed UxStylePatcher for Windows 11, restarted the PC and copied the themes from this [DeviantArt post](https://win7tbar.deviantart.com/art/Windows-7-Theme-for-Windows-10-692706139) to C:/Windows/Resources/Themes.

This works for the icons, but the window borders didn't change to look like Windows 7. I also tried another [DeviantArt post](https://www.deviantart.com/sagorpirbd/art/Aero-7-Themes-for-Win10-Final-523979941) and yet nothing.

I also tried activating Aero Lite via Winaero Tweaker, but it's not the same:

[image: Aero Lite borders]

Comment: Try to [Disable Transparency Effects](https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-11-disable-transparency-effects/).

Comment: @harrymc The transparency isn't that relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 11 Borders will not be Windows 7 Borders.  Not at all practical.

I have Windows 11 Production and Advanced Insider. If anything, it is moving farther away.

Things I do for Windows 11.

(a) Classic Theme.

(b) In Settings, Personalization, I show Accent Colors on Start and Task Bar and on Title bars and window borders.  Depending the app, this helps and is better in Production then current Insider.

So overall, your only hope is to adapt to Windows 11 and set as I noted to help as much as you can for your system.

Registry changes have been much reduced in Windows 11.

All of the above is for Native Windows 11 as changes to non-Native can be lost or cause issues with the next Feature Update.

Comment: By "Classic Theme" you say wallpaper? I was at best able to get taskbar and start menu from Windows 7 in Windows 11. I'm aware of the accent colors.

Comment: That is what I do (solid color) so as to eliminate any issues on the way desktop shows.  I have a Windows 7 VM here for comparison to Windows 7.  I also made note of Native Windows 11 as changes can be lost or changed with Feature Updates.

Answer (score 1):

BasicThemer2 gives you the aero basic Window borders without disabling DWM (Use RibbonDisabler with it as well)

https://github.com/Ingan121/BasicThemer2/releases

Comment: Yeah, I discovered it recently. Sadly it doesn't work well with the File Explorer.

Comment: You have to use RibbonDisabler to make it work properly because of some strange incompatibility